# ¿Cómo buscar en dos columnas a la vez desde el mismo campo?

Tags: java, android, buscador, busqueda

Tengo una **app** con un filtro que busca nombres en una tabla **SQLite** de varias columnas, la búsqueda es correcta en la columna "**nombre**", pero estoy tratando de que el filtro también busque por la columna "**categoría**" al mismo tiempo, aquí está el código que funciona con el nombre solo:

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return  false; }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            newText = newText.toLowerCase();
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ArrayList<EModelo> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (EModelo eModelo : mList)
            {
                String nombre = eModelo.getNombre().toLowerCase();

                if (nombre.contains(newText)) {
                    newList.add(eModelo);

                }
            }
            EAdapter.setFilter(newList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

¿Cómo le puedo agregar la columna "categoría" a la búsqueda?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, solo obten el valor de esta columna también y revisa si contiene el texto a buscar, si es así lo agregas a newList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione el filtro con los valores de la columna `nombre` y `categoria`, simplemente obtén el  valor de la columna categoría y compara si se contiene también en `newText`, si es así se agrega a la lista `newList` :

```
        ...
        ...
        for (EModelo eModelo : mList) {

            //*Obtiene valor columna nombre. 
            String nombre = eModelo.getNombre().toLowerCase();
          //*Obtiene valor columna categoria.
            String categoria = eModelo.getCategoria().toLowerCase();
            if (nombre.contains(newText) || categoria.contains(newText) ) {
                newList.add(eModelo);
            }



        }
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Gracias funciona pero me duplica todos los resultados lo que hice fue ésto if (nombre.contains(newText) || (categoria.contains(newText))) {
                        newList.add(eModelo); y no los duplica

Comment: Tienes razón , de hecho puede encargar encontrarse la coincidencia en ambas columnas, he modificado el còdigo.